# "script/generate cucumber" on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'm trying to use Cucumber with Ruby, Watir-Webdriver and without Rails. And that`s all on Windows :(

As I installed required gems ("cucumber", "webrat", "rspec", "win32console"), next step in instructions was

```
script/generate cucumber
```

that has to make a default structure, as I understood, for it`s files.

1. What is the command for this on Windows, and does it only generate structure? Because if so, I could create it manualy and not waste time for further search.
2. Are there any paths to be alse cofigured manually?

Comment: Have you tried running the command yet?

Comment: yes I did. It didn`t recognize the command script. Jarib had already explained that, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're following some pretty old instructions. You won't need webrat, but the other gems are fine.

You can check out the [examples](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/examples) provided by the author and simply run `rake cucumber` to run them.

Also you can read the advice on [standalone cucumber](http://gabrito.com/post/acceptance-testing-non-ruby-apps-with-cucumber) and then download a "starter kit" here: http://github.com/thuss/standalone-cucumber

Answer (score 2):

`script/generate cucumber` is a [cucumber-rails](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/) thing (and the instructions you're reading are even a bit outdated for Rails). If you're using Cucumber outside Rails, it's not something you can use.